# email sent using webform doesn't leave the server

Tags: email, g-suite

I have a reseller hosting plan on which I have my company web hosting account.

I have the email hosting pointing at a Google Apps Account and for the most part it works ... the problem comes with sites I have on the hosting account that send emails directly to the same email account from forms I have on the sites ... for some reason, those emails never get to the google apps account and are stored on the server.

I know because if I send emails from forms on the site, nothing comes to my inbox (configured to pull from google) but if I log in to cpanel and try go to view the email for the account, I see them there.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you just have to turn off local delivery on your server, this was the post that led me to it http://www.directadmin.com/forum/showthread.php?p=189477

If you use Cpanel/WHM then in WHM Main >> DNS Functions >> Edit MX Entry and pick "Remote Mail Exchanger"

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

What is your App using for it's outgoing mail server? Some hosting sites require you to use their mail server to send and some e-mail providers require that you be on their network or authenticate your account to send through them.

Depending on the way your app is sending the e-mail you may need to configure your outgoing mail server or authenticate to it.

Comment: Its not an app ... its just a php webform ... probably using sendmail or whatever is on the server